# Before ということは, can I use a compound complex sentence?

Tags: grammar

I know that before ということは, there can be a sentence. But can the sentence be a compound complex sentence? even though I am not sure if there is such a category in Japanese.

**Example 1**

> 【私は試験を受けたことがないのに、昨日彼女は私に問題をどう解くかを聞いてきた】ということは変ですね

**Example 2**

> 【彼は転校したばかりだけど、私はもう彼と仲良くなった】ということは意外です

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the answer is yes.

As for the sentences in the question, I don't really see the difference whether you parse it as e.g., (私は・・ないのに、)((昨日・・・聞いてきた)ということは変ですね。)  or (私は・・ないのに、昨日・・・聞いてきた)ということは変ですね. I understand that, if you have a cleft sentence in mind, then the translation should be *it is strange that, thought I've never taken the exam, she asked me how to solve problems*. But either way what is strange is her asking, so it means *I've never taken the exam, but she asked me for some reason*, which (in terms of structure) is closer to the former parsing with little difference in meaning.

Some more examples:

- 東京に住んでいた時彼がその喫茶店に通っていたということはみな知っていた
- Everybody knew that he often went to the coffee shop when he lived in Tokyo.
- 東京で地震があったとき、彼はまだ東京に来てなかったということは彼女は知らなかった
- She didn't know that he was not yet in Tokyo when there was an earthquake in Tokyo.

Technically there are still ambiguities (knowing happened at the time *when* clause happened), but such readings are unlikely.